# How do you disable a CComboBox in C++?

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog, modal-dialog

I've searched this extensively, and the answer I came up with about 20 times is to use CWnd::EnableWindow(FALSE). Currently, I have:

```
GetDlgItem(myComboBox)->EnableWindow(FALSE);
```

Instead of disabling the ComboBox, now the entire Dialog doesn't show up, and since it's a modal dialog (or at least I'm guessing that's the reason), the entire program gets locked up because I can't close the dialog if it's not there.

Is there a way to disable editing to this box without making it disappear entirely; similar to what SetReadOnly() does for a CEdit?

**Edit:**
Suddenly, the syntax above started working the next morning. I'm still not entirely sure why it didn't work in the first place.

Comment: Are you calling that API from a different thread other than the UI thread?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm unable to answer that with any confidence. It's a large code base, I am simply editing 2-3 classes at the moment.

Comment: Idea: Check your ressource file and check if the ressource ID is correctly assigned and unique. I remember from legacy MFC code bases where this was an issue.

Comment: @ChristianG Upon investigating the IDs a bit more thoroughly, I found that the ID number for the ComboBox is shared with  4 _other_ windows, but none of them are from the same dialog box. Should this make a difference?

Comment: @LLS2: no, because window IDs are only unique within their respectively dialog, multiple dialogs can reuse the same IDs. `GetDlgItem()` is relative to the dialog it is called on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`EnableWindow(FALSE)` is the correct function to call but your syntax looks like it may be incorrect (but it's hard to say with such a minimal example).

Is `myComboBox` an instance of `CComboBox`?  If so, I'd expect to see:

```
myComboBox.EnableWindow(FALSE);
```

or, using the associated resource ID:

```
((CComboBox*)GetDlgItem(IDC_MY_COMBO_BOX))->EnableWindow(FALSE);
```

Threading issues or duplicate resource ID's can also cause weird issues.

Comment: I apologize for the lack of clarity. "myComboBox" is the resource ID.

Comment: If you need clarification from the OP, a comment is the appropriate tool. Other than that, the `(CComboBox*)`-cast is unnecessary.

Comment: Then you should make sure that combo box's resource ID doesn't collide with the main window's id

Comment: I didn't have the cast originally, but even with it I'm seeing the same results. Parent window is no longer visible and the program freezes.

Comment: Also, the ID's for the main window and the ComboBox are different, so this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @LLS2 Where are you calling this code from?  The same dialog?

Comment: @JHH this code is called from the OnInitDialog() for this dialog

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to call `EnableWindow()` from a different thread than the dialog's

You could try this, and see if it works for you:

```
GetDlgItem(myComboBox)->PostMessage(WM_ENABLE, (WPARAM)FALSE);
```